# Dropping rows with pandas data frame when multiple Null values exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to go through each row in a data frame and checking if selected row has more than 3 null values (this part works) and then deleting the entire row. However, upon trying to drop said rows from the data frame, I'm met with an error:

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'**

Forgive me if this code is inefficient, I only need it to work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/mycsv.csv')


i = 0

while i < len(df.index):
    if df.iloc[i].isnull().sum() > 3:    
        df = df.drop(df.index[i], inplace = True)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with `thresh`, but because it is for non NaNs column need subtract length of columns:

```
np.random.seed(2021)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([np.nan, 1], size=(5,6)))
print (df)
     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
N = 3
df1 = df.dropna(thresh=len(df.columns) - N)
print(df1)
    0    1    2    3    4    5
0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
1 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
3 NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0


N = 2
df2 = df.dropna(thresh=len(df.columns) - N)
print(df2)
    0   1    2    3    4    5
3 NaN NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

You can filter rows if equal or less like `3 NaN`s in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
N = 3
df1 = df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1) <= N]
print (df1)
    0    1    2    3    4    5
0 NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
1 NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0
3 NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `threshold=X` as parameter of [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna) where X is the number of columns (`df.shape[1]`) minus your threshold (`3`).

Suppose this dataframe

```
>>> df
     0    1    2    3    4    5
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  # Drop (Nan = 6)
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  # Drop (Nan = 5)
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  # Drop (Nan = 4)
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  # Keep (Nan = 3)
4  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  # Keep (Nan = 2)
5  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  # Keep (Nan = 1)
6  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  # Keep (Nan = 0)
```

```
df = df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1] - 3)
print(df)

     0    1    2    3    4    5
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
5  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
6  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: ??? I posted my answer since 29 minutes. You add `dropna` to your answer there are 24 minutes...

Comment: Sure, but correct, not wrong.

Comment: And correct your answer after 22 minutes after post?

Comment: Sorry. I have a job...